# Videos won't play after upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04. Looks like a pipewire / wireplumber problem

Tags: upgrade, video, 23.04, pipewire, wireplumber

After upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04, I started having intermittent problems with youtube videos. The audio starts fine. I'll see a few frames of video, while the audio continues. After about 15 seconds, the video and audio loops back to the start.

After I reinstalled wireplumber, it worked for awhile. Then it stopped again.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I've been wondering about this too. I filed a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/2031252 for general audio problems, but I'm not sure what package is actually causing this.